# I can't push to master branch from one computer, I can from another

Tags: git, gitlab

I pushed some code to the protected master branch of a new project in Gitlab.

Then I pulled the project on another computer.

Both computers (my desktop computer and my laptop) are set up with the same credentials for git.
They have the same ssh keys.

On the second computer I can't push to the protected master branch.
Where do I look to see differences in credentials on both computers?
I use Ubuntu on both computers, and git from a shell.

This is the error message I get:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.
To git@vcs.xxxxxx.nl:xxxxx/xxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@vcs.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git'
```

edit: I now can't push from both computers. I'll check with the owner of the repo.

Comment: You start  by posting the error message you get

Comment: you need to talk to the server admin about why that hook is failing to identify you

Comment: I will. He called in sick today. However, my question was, how can I push to the repo from one computer and not from another that has identical credentials? In other words, how are these credentials different in a way I can't seem to find?

Comment: Without knowing the content of the pre-receive hook we would have to speculate.  It could be looking at something in the commit itself (like the author name), and not have anything to do with your credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see that your `~/.gitconfig` is the same (you might have certificate or something defined)

Second thing is to restart the ssh-agent

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Now try to pull/fetch and see if you can.

Comment: I had already checked ~/.gitconfig. I typed the command you suggested, now git wants a password. It doesn't accept the password I type. I reset the password on the gitlab web gui, but still, git won't accept it.

Comment: so use sudo to run it

Comment: On my laptop, I can push and pull to/from master and develop. On my desktop, I can push/pull to develop, pull from master, not push to master. I can't find the thing that obviously must be different on both computers.

Comment: Maybe your server has protected configuration for IP or computer name?